# Scala build script - no projects defined in build unit

Tags: scala, sbt

I just ried to set up an SBT-Project with a custom Scala-based build script, but I recieve the following error message:

```
[error] No projects defined in build unit /home/user/scala/myProject
```

the myProject directory is looking like this:

```
├── project
│   ├── myProjectBuild.scala
│   └── target
├── src
│   └── main
└── target
    ├── resolution-cache
    ├── scala-2.9.2
    └── streams
```

and here the content of myProjectBuild.scala:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object myProjectBuild extends Build {
    val myProjectDependencies = List(
        "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.1" % "test"
    )

    val myProjectSettings = List(
        name := "myProject",
        version := "1.0",
        scalaVersion := "2.11.5",
        libraryDependencies := myProjectDependencies
    )

    override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ myProjectSettings
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between [Bare Build Definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Bare-Def.html), [Multi-Project .sbt definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Basic-Def.html) and [Scala Build Definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Full-Def.html). About the first one:

> Unlike Multi-project .sbt build definition and .scala build definition
>   that explicitly define a Project definition, bare build definition
>   implicitly defines one based on the location of the .sbt file.
>
> Instead of defining Projects, bare .sbt build definition consists of a
>   list of Setting[_] expressions.
>
> The current recommendation is to use Multi-project .sbt build definition.

So, it allows you to not specify any project explicitly, but it's pretty obsolete and not much recommended to use.

P.S. I suppose you're reading some outdated revision of "Learning Scala" (instead of [this](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030287.do)) or the author uses `.sbt`-build based example.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the problem. I added the following lines to the scala build file:

```
lazy val root = Project(id = "HardyHeron",
   base = file("."),
   settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ hardyHeronSettings)
```

After that it nearly worked but I got an MissingRequirementError because of the line

```
libraryDependencies := myProjectDependencies
```

After changing it to

```
libraryDependencies ++= myProjectDependencies
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317326/trying-to-cross-compile-a-project-to-scala-2-11-fails-with-error-while-loading), it compiled properly. I'm not sury why it's working now. The book which I'm referring to (Learning Scala) offers a scala build file without defining the rool val. So should it run without this line anyway?